# SQL is there a way to filter results based on a priority logic

Tags: sql

Hi I get the following results on SQL Server

| id | Source |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | A |
| id1 | B |
| id2 | A |

I would like to filter out results with source A as long as B exists, otherwise keep results with Source A.
The result should be
Line 2 and Line 3.
Thanks in advance.

Within the where condition set Source conditionally.

Attempt:

```
select * from t a 
where source = 'A' and 
      exists (select 1 from t b where b.source = 'B' and b.id = a.id)
```

| id | Source |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | A |
| id2 | A |

But correct result should be:

| id | Source |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | B |
| id2 | A |

Comment: Please include your attempt at solving this with SQL.

Comment: Tag your DBMS (Postgres, Sql Server, Oracle, etc).

Comment: `select * from t where source = 'A' and exists (select 1 from t b where b.source = 'B' and b.id = a.id)` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but I am guessing this should yield the required result

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.source,a.source) as source 
from t as a 
left join 
(
select * 
from t as b 
where b.source = 'B' 
) as b on b.id = a.id
where a.source = 'A' and 
      b.id = a.id
```